# How to make search bar width 100%

Tags: css, searchbar

I'm trying to set the search bar width for user search to 100%, but the code I've tried doesn't work when entered into the CSS.

This is the code I've tried to input into the CSS:

```
 .um-directory .um-member-directory-header .um-member-directory-header-row .um-member-directory-search-line {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But this is unsuccessful.

How can I achieve this?

Here's the page: https://slapperoni.com/members/

Comment: Can you attach an image of how you would like it to look?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://ibb.co/0MBksML

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

How about giving `flex: 1` to the input element?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

```html
<div style="
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
">
  <input style="flex: 1;">
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

[image: demo]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How exactly would I enter this into the CSS?

Comment: Can you post your html file and css file?